# Results from DTU analysis tutorial not what they should be?

Tags: r

I’m currently following a differential transcript usage (DTU) analysis tutorial ([link here](https://f1000research.com/articles/7-952/v3)) and am using the sample datasets provided by the authors. However, my results stop matching those from the tutorial after I create a dmDSdata object and filter it (I’ve included the code below). Creating the object works fine, but after filtering and estimating model parameters, the results tables I produce show different genes and transcripts from the ones shown in the tutorial:

```
# Load the DRIMSeq package and create a dmDSdata object with the
# counts and samples data frames
library(DRIMSeq)
dmDS <- dmDSdata(counts = counts, samples = samples)
dmDS # returns information about the number of genes

# Each row of the dmDSdata object contains all the transcripts corresponding
# to a particular gene
methods(class = class(dmDS))
counts(dmDS[1,])[,1:4]

# Filter the dmDS object before estimating model parameters
n       <- 12 # the total number of samples
n.small <- 6  # sample size of the smallest group
dmDS    <- dmFilter(dmDS,
                 min_samps_feature_expr = n.small, min_feature_expr = 10 ,
                 min_samps_feature_prop = n.small, min_feature_prop = 0.1,
                 min_samps_gene_expr    = n,       min_gene_expr    = 10)
dmDS

# Find out how many of the genes remaining after filtering have N isoforms
# by counting the number of unique gene IDs and tabulating the results
table(table(counts(dmDS)$gene_id))

# Create a design matrix using a design formula as well as the sample
# information contained in the dmDS object (accessed via samples.csv)
design_full <- model.matrix(~condition, data = DRIMSeq::samples(dmDS))
colnames(design_full)

# To accelerate the subsequent steps, subset to the first 250 genes
dmDS <- dmDS[1:250,]

# Estimating model parameters and testing for differential transcript use
# Estimate the precision, which is inversely related to dispersion in the
# Dirichlet Multinomial model
# Fit regression coefficients
# Perform null hypothesis testing on the coefficient of interest
set.seed(1)
system.time({
  dmDS <- dmPrecision(dmDS, design = design_full )
  dmDS <- dmFit      (dmDS, design = design_full )
  dmDS <- dmTest     (dmDS, coef   = "condition2")
})

# Tabulate the results, including a p-value per gene or a p-value per transcript
#   p-value per gene: is there DTU within this gene?
#   p-value per transcript: has the proportion of this transcript changed within
#   its parent gene?
results     <- DRIMSeq::results(dmDS)                           # per gene
results.txp <- DRIMSeq::results(dmDS, level = "feature")        # per transcript
```

At this point, the results I *should* get are as follows:

```
head(results)
##              gene_id        lr   df     pvalue   adj_pvalue
## 1 ENSG00000000457.13  1.493561   4 8.277814e-01 9.120246e-01
## 2 ENSG00000000460.16  1.068294   3 7.847330e-01 9.101892e-01
## 3 ENSG00000000938.12  4.366806   2 1.126575e-01 2.750169e-01
## 4 ENSG00000001084.11  1.630085   3 6.525877e-01 8.643316e-01
## 5 ENSG00000001167.14  28.402587  1 9.853354e-08 5.007113e-07
## 6 ENSG00000001461.16  9.815460   1 1.730510e-03 6.732766e-03

head(results.txp)
##              gene_id         feature_id         lr   df  pvalue adj_pvalue
## 1 ENSG00000000457.13  ENST00000367771.10 0.16587607  1 0.6838032  0.9171007
## 2 ENSG00000000457.13  ENST00000367770.5  0.01666448  1 0.8972856  0.9788571
## 3 ENSG00000000457.13  ENST00000367772.8  1.02668495  1 0.3109386  0.6667146
## 4 ENSG00000000457.13  ENST00000423670.1  0.06046507  1 0.8057624  0.9323782
## 5 ENSG00000000457.13  ENST00000470238.1  0.28905766  1 0.5908250  0.8713427
## 6 ENSG00000000460.16  ENST00000496973.5  0.83415788  1 0.3610730  0.7232298
```

However, what I see in the R console is the following:

```
head(results)
##              gene_id         lr   df     pvalue   adj_pvalue
## 1 ENSG00000237094.12  52.9721358  1 3.383138e-13 2.532227e-12
## 2 ENSG00000237491.8   2.7403807   1 9.784145e-02 3.179847e-01
## 3 ENSG00000228794.8   6.9271154   2 3.131814e-02 1.330626e-01
## 4 ENSG00000187961.13  0.9699384   2 6.157162e-01 8.934371e-01
## 5 ENSG00000217801.9   0.2262070   1 6.343506e-01 8.934371e-01
## 6 ENSG00000131591.17  30.4292202  1 3.462727e-08 2.136131e-07

head(results.txp)
##              gene_id        feature_id         lr   df     pvalue   adj_pvalue
## 1 ENSG00000237094.12 ENST00000599771.6  52.9721358  1 3.383138e-13 3.341499e-12
## 2 ENSG00000237094.12 ENST00000608420.1  52.9721358  1 3.383138e-13 3.341499e-12
## 3 ENSG00000237491.8  ENST00000585826.1  2.7403807   1 9.784145e-02 3.528888e-01
## 4 ENSG00000237491.8  ENST00000592547.1  2.7403807   1 9.784145e-02 3.528888e-01
## 5 ENSG00000228794.8  ENST00000445118.6  0.4788971   1 4.889223e-01 8.378376e-01
## 6 ENSG00000228794.8  ENST00000449005.5  0.5862693   1 4.438654e-01 8.201190e-01
```

I have tried switching from R version 4.1 and Bioconductor version 13.3 to the older ones used in the tutorial, but I got error messages when trying to download the rnaseqDTU package which said it was not available to older versions of Bioconductor. As I use RStudio, I also tried clearing my global environment and running the code again, but that did not work either. I’m not sure what to do about this issue and would appreciate any potential solutions! Thanks.